# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I am getting an error while running my spring boot maven application. I am not sure what is wrong.

looks like an error with some dependencies.can someone help please.

I tried removing some dependencies but that didn't help.

---

```
import javax.persistence.*; 
import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern; 
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank; 
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
```

---

I am using the following imports for my application

Here is my pom.xml file

**pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.system</groupId>
    <artifactId>bank</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bank</name>
    <description>service for basic banking operations</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Attached below is the error i receive when i try to run my service
Error on Run:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:65)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.String javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()'

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/Users/navinagarwalla/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.2.0.Final/hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/internal/xml/config/ValidationBootstrapParameters.class

The called method's class, javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/navinagarwalla/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
    jar:file:/Users/navinagarwalla/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration: file:/Users/navinagarwalla/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters and javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Remove the `javax.validation` dependency (managed through `spring-boot-starter-validation`) and the same goes for `jakarta.persistence` which is managed through `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Leaving them will lead to issues when upgrading to a newer Spring Boot version (as it ties your app to a certain version, which can lead to surprising result later).

Answer (score 1):

Adding this dependency resolved the issue, i was using "1.1.0 Final" as the version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Remove that dependency, that is already included and managed by `spring-boot-starter-validation`. Including it explicitly might (or rather will) lead to issues when upgrading Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Remove version declaration for javax validation API and let Maven pull from the managed dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```